# Can Firefox on android be set to open bookmarks in current tab rather than opening in an new tab?

Tags: firefox-for-android, bookmarks

I am running LineageOS 16.0.20200308 (android version 9) on a Samsung Note 3 (hlte) and have Firefox 94.1.2 installed.  When I open a bookmark in Firefox it opens in a new tab and I would prefer the default behaviour to open in the current tab.  I have not found a place in the settings for this behaviour.  Does anyone know how I can change this behaviour?

Comment: If there's nothing in the setting or browser flags, then I doubt if it's possible at all.

Comment: How do I access the browser flags?